# Why is Poyo completely round?

Tags: poyopoyo-kansatsu-nikki

The premise of Poyopoyo Kansatsu Nikki is that it's about a cat who is completely round.

[image]

Does the series ever reveal why Poyo is so unusually shaped?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, it is never revealed. The series is more interested in poking fun at the foibles of animals and everyday life in general, than examining the strange physical dimensions of its protagonist(?).

The most likely reasons are for [the Moe](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Moe) and [the lulz](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny); that round cat design is aesthetically cute, which is sufficient reason for inclusion within a light comedy. Also the roundness gives all sorts of opportunities for rolling away gags. Plus, the shape of the cat probably reminds its viewers about balls, pork buns and rice balls. Any one of these things that are animate would be rather amusing :)